# Movie identification: Movie with alien type insects fighting on desert type planet against marines

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can't remember much about the movie, just that the aliens were kind of insect like and had something to do with using the humans brains for something. One key part of the movie I remember is a guy sacrificing himself to detonate an explosive to save his friends from said aliens. The humans fighting against the aliens are some kind of army.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a -1.  It's perfectly OK to not be aware of Starship Troopers and the description in the question is sufficient to identify it.  +1 to offset.

Comment: I'm with @JimmyShelter on this. +1 just to stick it to whoever downvoted.

Answer (score 23):

Sounds very much like [*Starship Troopers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_%28film%29). I don't recall any sort of sacrificial bomb scene, but it's possible you're thinking of the part when Denise Richards' love interest allows himself to be killed by the brain bug in order to help her figure out how to kill it. Or it could be one of the sequels; I've never seen them.

Comment: It also sounds like [Starship Troopers 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0367093/)

Comment: and probably *Starship Troopers 3: Marauder* as well.

Comment: *Do you want to know more?* ;)

Comment: There is Starship troopers 4 as well, invasion...

Comment: The sacrificial bomb scene is slightly after the brain bug scene - when Denise Richards is rescued, one Trooper is injured and stays behind with a nuke.

Comment: @thegrinner: I don't remember that part. It's been years since I watched that film, even though I own a copy. It's not very good, and I watched it dozens of times as a teenager. I remember the commentary more than the actual film, I think.

Comment: @Major Stackings - Actually no, **Starship Troopers 3** didn't take place on a desert planet, mostly it was Casper and Jolene trying to act in a military complex (Yes, I watched them all and the cartoon).  The 1st movie took place on several worlds and in space where the 2nd took place on one desert planet and in the end there's a sacrificial to save the team. The new version is supposed to actually follow the book but I really enjoyed what Paul Verhoeven did when he reimagined it.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I hate to admit it, but I really enjoyed the first film, warts and all. I didn't see the others though.

Comment: @Major Stackings - That's because Paul Verhoeven is the man!  You might actually like the 2nd flick, it more like a really long episode of **The Outer Limits** than a sequel to the first.  The rest are rather awful, and I say that without malice.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza: I have to disagree with you on your first point. The planet that Jolene & crew crashed on in the latter half of Part 3 did look rather like a desert. In fact, it looked remarkably similar to whatever location was used in the first movie.